# Add user custom select item to selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I need to add a user custom select item to a select one menu, shown as last item below:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="mail_house" value="#{projectDataService.mailer.mail_house}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="DOCUMATION" itemValue="DOCUMATION" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="NCA" itemValue="NCA_ACP" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="JS DIRECT" itemValue="JSPOD DIRECT" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="PLATINUM" itemValue="PLATINUMDIRECT" />
    // User customized entry as opposed to the available items.
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="OTHER" itemValue="COLLECT USER INPUT TEXT HERE" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am very new to JSF but you need some "static" fixed values insted of dynamic ones ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia Yea I know how the general drop down box works, my question is, is there a way to do this via jquery or javascript? There has to be something right?

Comment: So, you basically want an editable dropdown (a combobox)? Does `editable="true"` as shown in the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) satisfy?

Comment: @BalusC Let me check it out and get back to you